# How do I make a random value not repeat itself? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make it so that every time I run the code the item of this array that shows up will be different. Here is the code I've done so far.

```
let array = ["apple","orange"];

randomItem = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];


if(randomItem != document.getElementById('spaceText').innerHTML){
   document.getElementById('spaceText').innerHTML = randomItem;
} else while(randomItem == document.getElementById('spaceText').innerHTML){
    randomItem = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to finish this .. here is how I'm looking at the problem,

1. You have an array that includes several strings you want to pick from
2. you want to generate a random number to select one item from the array
3. you want to check if the selected item is equal to the content of the html element of yours.
4. if not, then you would like to insert that item into the html element
5. if it is equal you want to generate another random number

Comment: what is `else while` ?

Comment: _Shuffle_ your array, and then pick the items from it one by one in order You did not specify whether you need this just “on” one single page, or across multiple requests - if the latter, then you will also have to store that shuffled array and the current index you picked somewhere (local-/sessionStorage, cookie, session, …)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Because what you are describing sort of reminds me [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned I'm still very new to this so forgive me if there are some statements I muddled up.

Comment: so the result is, the innerHTML would eventually be a string of the combined elements of the array? like would it append to the current innerHTML or totally replace it.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

- You could build a new array without the value you don't want, and choose a random from that.
- You could also make a loop which keeps going until you get a value you want.
- You could also move the value you don't want to the end of the array, swapping place, and then choose a value within `upperBound - 1`.
- You could also just remove the value you get from the array each time, if you don't want it to appear at all again.

There are multiple ways that all depend on the context and goal of the system.

Comment: This was my interview question years and years ago. I always liked the first approach with new array. I'll upvote. :)

Comment: So I tried to the new array approach but I have no idea how to remove one single item from an array to another, slice takes two positions.

Comment: Try with [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: how would I do the 4th approach, as the item needs to not be repeated ?

Comment: You would remove the chosen item from the array. Then next time you try to get a random value from the array, the former value is not present.

Comment: would I remove it using .slice(randomItem,1);

Comment: I recommend trying out the different possibilities in the browser console. Just build an array, try the different methods and investigate the result. That way you would learn how it works, and be able to find the solution that best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't have to generate a random number more than once, just use  filter method

```js
const array = ["Apple","Orange","Cherry","Banana","Pear"];
const spaceText = document.getElementById('spaceText');

function randomText() {    
  //the next fruit cannot equal the current text content
  const options = array.filter(fruit => fruit !== spaceText.textContent);
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
  console.log("Random fruit is:",options[randomIndex]);
  spaceText.textContent = options[randomIndex];
}
```

```html
<div id="spaceText">Apple</div>

<button onclick="randomText()">Randomize</button>
```

Comment: This is brilliant pavlos, but why are you using constants in this ?

Comment: The variables never need to be redefined, therefore const is best practice. They get erased within the function's scope each time it gets executed.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is literally my first month coding in JS and I'm learning plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? All it does is selecting a new item from the array and taking care that it is not the one that was selected previously

```js
const items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

let selectedItemIndex;

function selectNewOne() {
  const randomItemIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

  if (randomItemIndex === selectedItemIndex) {
    return selectNewOne();
  }

  return randomItemIndex;
}

// this is just for testing purposes
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  selectedItemIndex = selectNewOne();
  console.log(items[selectedItemIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, Keep the random number in object (or set) and generate new random until you found not already seen one. Generator function will be helpful to do that.

```js
const getRandomUniqueInList = function* (arr) {
  const myRandom = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) % arr.length);
  const list = [];

  while (list.length < arr.length) {
    let index = myRandom();
    while (list.includes(index)) {
      index = myRandom();
    }
    list.push(index);
    yield index;
  }
  return -1;
};

const items = new Array(10).fill(0);

const itr = getRandomUniqueInList(items);
let next = itr.next();

while (!next.done) {
  console.log('Random: ', next.value);
  next = itr.next();
}
```

Another variant for get random upto specified max number and implement with `Set` and generator method.

```js
const getRandomUpto = function* (max = 50) {
  const myRandom = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
  const set = new Set();

  let rand = myRandom();
  while (set.size < max) {
    while (set.has(rand)) {
      rand = myRandom();
    }
    set.add(rand);
    yield rand;
  }
};

const sample_max = 10;
const itr = getRandomUpto(sample_max);

let next = itr.next();

while(!next.done) {
  const myRandom = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * sample_max);
  console.log('Random, (not repeat):', next.value, '(may repeat): ', myRandom());
  next = itr.next()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample. You are using innerHTML which assumed to be string. So the approach is when you trigger the function, pull a random element/word from the array, then matches if it exists in the current innerHTML value, if it is true, it will skip it else it will append the random word into the innerHTML.

This could work with arrays as well as an alternative to innerHTML / string

```js
let array = ["apple","orange", "banana","cherry","strawberry" ];

random = () =>{ 

 let randomItem = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
 let currentString = document.getElementById('spaceText').innerHTML
 
 if( ! (parseFloat(currentString.indexOf(randomItem)) >=0) ){
  currentString += ' '+randomItem
  document.getElementById('spaceText').innerHTML = currentString
 }else{
  console.log(randomItem+' already exists')
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="spaceText">Inital value</div>

<button onclick="random()">Random</button>
```